# How can I write a method that does not involve method logic in the name, yet accommodates various algorithms (in Java)?

Tags: design-patterns, methods, interface

I am writing a Java application that must communicate with a device that accepts its own language consisting of command sequences (a series of bytes) over a secure shell channel.

For the purpose of simplicity, there are named read/write fields on this device

1. `fieldAlpha`
2. `fieldBeta`
   ...
3. `fieldn`

that I can **get** and **set** on this device.

The command sequence is created out of a StringBuilder object, which consists of a

- prefix
- optional setter payload (for setter)
- suffix

A command sequence looks like `<ESC>ABC*somerandomvalueDEF<LF>`.

After writing about 20 of these, I figured there MUST be a more maintainable way to handle this.

```
public String getFieldAlpha() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append((char) 0x1B).append("ABC").append("DEF").append((char) 0x0D);
    byte[] command = sb.toString().getBytes();
    String response = (sendMessage(command));
    return response;
}

public String setFieldAlpha(String alpha) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append((char) 0x1B).append("ABC*").append(alpha).append("DEF").append((char) 0x0D);
    byte[] command = sb.toString().getBytes();
    String response = (sendMessage(command));
    return response;
}

public String getFieldBeta() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append((char) 0x1B).append("OPQ").append("RST").append((char) 0x0D);
    byte[] command = sb.toString().getBytes();
    String response = (sendMessage(command));
    return response;
}

public String setFieldBeta(String beta) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append((char) 0x1B).append("OPQ*").append(beta).append("RST").append((char) 0x0D);
    byte[] command = sb.toString().getBytes();
    String response = (sendMessage(command));
    return response;
}

// ... and so forth
```

I suspect a better design for an API would be two methods that select functions based on parameters. I am hung up on the fact that the command sequence changes depending on the field.

1. `getField()`
2. `setField(Method FieldName, String value)`

Or is there an even better way I am not thinking about? I looked possibly using Enum Objects to set the prefix and suffix of field command sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this is with a **HashMap** that maps a field to a message format. If you have a different formats for getting a field and setting a field you will need two **HashMaps**.

Your application will have to call methods for each field, so you can add two methods: **setField(string fieldName, string fieldValue)** and **getField(string fieldName)**.

You can add a static class that will contain the fields.

```
public class Fields {

  public final string Alpha = "Alpha";
  public final string Alpha = "Beta";
  // ......
}
```

Add a factory to separate the responsibility of message creation to a special object:

```
  public class MessageFactory {

    private HashMap<string, string> mFieldNameMessageFormatMap;

    public MessageFactory() {

       mFieldNameMessageFormatMap = HashMap<string, string>();

       // Initialize your formats here. These are just for example and are not 
          correct

       mFieldNameMessageFormatMap.put(Fields.Alpha, "<ESC>ABC*%sDEF<LF>");
       mFieldNameMessageFormatMap.put(Fields.Beta, "<ESC>OPQ*%sRST<LF>");
    }

    public string createGetFielMessage(string fieldName) {
       return String.format(mFieldNameMessageFormatMap.get(fieldName), "");
    }

    public void createSetFieldMessage(string fieldName, string value) {
       return String.format(mFieldNameMessageFormatMap.get(fieldName), value);
    }
  }
```

Then your code becomes:

```
 public void getValue(string fieldName) {
   return sendMessage(mMessageFactory.createGetFieldValue(fieldName));
 }

 public void setValue(string fieldName, string value) {
   return sendMessage(mMessageFactory.createSetFieldValue(fieldName), value);
 }

 // usage:

 string fieldValue = getValue(Fields.Alpha);

 setValue(Fields.Alpha);
```

Adding new fields is easy. You just need to add the field to **Fields** class and add the formatting to the **Factory**

This way you don't have to write a method for each field and your code won't have *'magic strings'* in it.

Comment: I see, sorry... you said that you are designing an interface between the app and the device, so I assumed that you are also defining the format. I'll remove this part of my answer. Stiff the other part is the same. A HashMap should do it to map a field to a special format.

Comment: I reworded my ques. Nice answer. Exactly what I was looking for: combining a String formatter with a class that can generate messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help.  :)

Comment: I may have jumped the gun. I realized that your answer does not actually solve the problem. Each field has two different message formats, depending on whether setting or getting a field from the device. For example, field ALPHA uses the prefix ABC* when setting and ABC when getting. But this * is inconsistent in some cases. It might as well be ABC* and XUQ.

Comment: In case you have different formats, you can use 2 HashMaps. one for getValue and one for setValue, the code for this is still isolated in the Factory

Comment: I guess it is also normal to make the factory methods static (in addition to the MessageFactory class) to ensure they always exist (singleton), because I need to call them from a super class. And make everything private so that the create methods can only be accessed from the super class.

Comment: Sure :) I didn't make it static because some developers prefer to avoid static classes, but in this case you can. If you have tests and you like to be able to mock the MessageFactory making it static will be a problem. In case you wan't to do tests, you have to add also an interface for the message factory. This will add additional complexity and more classes/interfaces, so if you don't need the ability to mock the factory just make it static to simplify things :)